# Imaginary term in Integration procedure

Tags: numerical-integration, symbolic

How do you remove the imaginary term in the integrated output? Compare the outcome from the operations below. The first operation yields an imaginary term, while the second one has none.

```
Clear[a, c];
Integrate[q^2 ((4 (c π))/((a q^2 - c) (c + a q^2))), {q, 0, ∞}]
Integrate[q^2 ((4 (c π))/((a q^2 - c) (c + a q^2))), q]
Limit[(Sqrt[c] π (2 ArcTan[(Sqrt[a] q)/Sqrt[c]] + 
      Log[Sqrt[c] - Sqrt[a] q] - Log[Sqrt[c] + Sqrt[a] q]))/a^(3/2), q -> ∞]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put assumptions in:

```
Clear[a, c]
Integrate[
 q^2 ((4 (c π))/((a q^2 - c) (c + a q^2))), {q, 0, ∞}, 
 Assumptions -> {a, c} ∈ Reals]

(* ConditionalExpression[(Sqrt[c] π^2)/a^(3/2), (a > 0 && c > 0) || (a < 0 && c < 0)] *)
```